Mui Checkbox: How to show error message if the checkbox is required
So far I have tried to show the error message with divs but it's not robust. It should be passed from the parent. I also tried using the using yup for handling the validation but i think i did something wrong in there. Please help with this

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Check this if it's helpful. You should provide some code snippet or sandbox for anybody else to understand.
